# Why is return not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

http://jsfiddle.net/2Ny8x/116/

Making a simple to do application. Why is it that I can't return `42` for `$scope.incompleteCount`?

```
var model = { user: 'Jimmy',
              items:[{ action: 'Buy Flowers', done: false},
                     { action: 'Wash Car', done: false},
                     { action: 'Walk Dog', done: false}]}

var ToDoApp = angular.module('ToDoApp', []);

ToDoApp.controller('TasksController', function($scope){
    $scope.user = model['user'];
    $scope.tasks = model['items'];
    $scope.incompleteCount = function(){ return 42 };
});
```

Html:

```
{{ user }} <!-- = 'Jimmy' -->
{{ incompleteCount }} <!-- expected 42, get nothing at all, just a blank -->
```

Comment: Because it is a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to make a function call, which can be done as below.

```
{{ incompleteCount() }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are giving the function.
Replace

```
 $scope.incompleteCount = function(){ return 42 };
```

with

```
 $scope.incompleteCount = function(){ return 42 }();
```

Now it actually executes that function and returns the value.